# please tell how can i findout node object of any attribute

Tags: xml, vb.net

i have got a object of attribute and i want to know what is its node name (who contain this attribut) .. please give me solution (vb.net preferable)..

Comment: What XML API are you using (System.XML, System.XML.Linq, etc.)?  What does your XML look like?  Do you have any code so far that you can post to help us?

Comment: using System.XML

Dim children As XmlNodeList = node.ChildNodes
        For Each child As XmlNode In children
Dim attrs As XmlAttributeCollection = child.Attributes
            For Each attr As XmlAttribute In attrs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say I think I know what you want. The name of the node from a given attribute.

How about something like

```
Dim s As String = "<nodelist><node><val id=""test""/></node></nodelist>"
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(s)
Dim attribute As XmlAttribute = doc.SelectSingleNode("//nodelist/node/val").Attributes(0)
Dim name As String = attribute.OwnerElement.Name
```

Comment: exactly.. what i am looking for....thanks lot.... you guys are doing great job.. you should be proud of it..

Answer (score 1):

With `XmlDocument`:

```
        string xml = @"<xml><el att=""abc""/></xml>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlAttribute attr = (XmlAttribute)
            doc.SelectSingleNode("//@att");
        string elName = attr.OwnerElement.Name;
```

or with `XDocument`:

```
        string xml = @"<xml><el att=""abc""/></xml>";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        XAttribute attr = ((XElement)doc.Root.FirstNode).FirstAttribute;
        string elName = attr.Parent.Name.LocalName;
```